# Spring security: External Authorization

Tags: spring-security, integration, wso2

I successfully completed login module of my application using spring security's inbuilt authentication & authorization mechanism.But later i was told to check if i can integrate `WSO2` (`SOA solution as external Authorization mechanism`) with `Spring` security so that i can use Spring security's authentication mechanism alone and `WSO2` for authorization instead of using Spring security provided Authorization.

I did search & read the documentation and i could get details about using External authentication with Spring security & nothing about External authorization.I would like to know if i can do the same and also how i can do it.Any pointers will be really helpful for me.

Comment: You want to add this authorization logic using the `PreAuthorize` and other related annotations? Or do you need a completely independent way?

Comment: @BhashitParikh - I'm looking for a complete independent way and I v'e figured out a way to do this.I'll post the updates as i try out.